# MySQL - Getting the average in a column

Tags: php, mysql, math

I'm making a list with certain songs. Each song has its own unique ID. OK let's say I have this table called `list`. A new:

[image]

The ID is self-explanatory. It's used to ID rows. `song_one` through `song_ten` is filled with a song's unique ID.

Every time a user makes a new `list`, they add songs and each row gets filled. Now, how would I get the average rank of the songs in the tables `list` using the song's ID that is filled between `song_one` through `song_ten`?

Comment: Having columns called `song_one` through `song_ten` may be a sign that you need to rethink your database design. It is very difficult to work with such designs, and if you later want to change it to top twenty, it won't be a simple change.

Comment: That's the problem. I kinda rushed the DB but can you help me? How would I redesign it?

Comment: You should study database normalization before redesigning the db, there are plenty sources on that subject on the internet.  After reading about the 3 most relevant normal forms you'll most probably find other issues with your db design, therefore just fixing this one is not really the best approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redesign your database. Make a new table with songid, listid and rank. This will make your job easy.

```
listsongs
-----------------
songid [PK] -- Foreign key referencing the songs table
listid [PK] -- Foreign key referencing the lists table
rank
```

Selecting average song ranks:

```
SELECT
    a.song_id
    AVG(b.rank) AS avgrank
FROM
    songs a
LEFT JOIN
    listsongs b PM a.song_id = b.song_id
GROUP BY
    a.song_id
```

Comment: I have a table called `songs` that stores the song's name, artist, album, etc. And `listid` being this... but what about rank?

Comment: Rank means position 1st 2nd (upto 10 in your case)

Comment: Then you can use select avg(rank) from songs group by songid

Comment: That's exactly the table I sort of made.. I think it will work: http://i.imgur.com/RJphD.png

Answer (score 1):

Please do as others have said about normalizing your DB structure. If you wish to continue with this design however, you can use this clunky-looking solution:

```
SELECT 
    a.song_id,
    AVG(
        CASE
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_one THEN 1
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_two THEN 2
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_three THEN 3
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_four THEN 4
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_five THEN 5
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_six THEN 6
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_seven THEN 7
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_eight THEN 8
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_nine THEN 9
            WHEN a.song_id = b.song_ten THEN 10
        END
    ) AS AvgRank
FROM
    songs a
INNER JOIN
    list b ON 
        a.song_id IN 
        (
            b.song_one,
            b.song_two,
            b.song_three,
            b.song_four,
            b.song_five,
            b.song_six,
            b.song_seven,
            b.song_eight,
            b.song_nine,
            b.song_ten
        )
GROUP BY
    a.song_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I would listen to @*Mark Byers* and @*Shehzad Bilal*, who said that you need to redesign your database structure.

When you think in the terms of tables and their attributes, think logical - think in the terms of code.

For example: If you are writing to a file, would it be easier to create a universal loop to output all the things needed, or to open the file with different pieces of code every time you needed to write something.

In your database, it would be easier to have one table that represents the song itself (that is the general idea behind a database design) than having a table that represents all the songs.

```
(table) (attribute)
 song
         id
         albumid (fk from table album)
         name
         title
         (...etc)
 list
         id
         songid (fk from table song)
         ip
         date
         (...etc)
```

If you wanted to create a ranking system, you would do it through code. In some cases, purely depending on your design, you would have a table for it, but it would also be universal.

Comment: A list may contain *many* songs; one song may be contained by *many* lists. Why do you suggest only one `songid` field as a foreign key in the `lists` table? You need a cross-reference table to facilitate the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: That isn't the lists table, that is an example of the list table. Instead of having all the songs (which is impossible) in the list table, it should be referenced to only one. The many-to-many relationship should be solved with an additional table. I explained the ranking in the last two sentences.